# UIActivityView attach file to Email

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, email, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've created an `UIActivityView` inside my iPad App but I don't know how to attach a file when sending an email. How can I do?

Comment: Gimme code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it will help you.

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFilePath];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", pdfData] applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but what if you want to name the PDF, like "MyAppName.pdf" instead of the generic "Attachment-1" (without extension) that Mail uses when attaching with this code.

Comment: Hmm... this is good question!) Maybe this is not exactly what you mean, but I think this is much better                         NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppDistributionGuide" ofType:@"pdf"];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str]] applicationActivities:nil];

Comment: @Mrwolfy did you find and answer for your comment ? I need to do exactly the same

Comment: @Pach if I'm not wrong, you can store file with needed for you name on the disk and then use code above, hope it will help you.