# UIActivityViewController - preserve file name of attached files from read from URL

Tags: ios, xcode, email, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is there an equivalent code to this (code below) for iOS6 UIActivityViewController? The question is, can I share data via url and preserve the file name? As of now the only way I can figure out how to do it is to convert the PDF to NSData and add the data as an activityItem. Works fine, but I lose the name of the attached pdf.

```
[composer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"myPDF.pdf"];
```

Comment: yes I think it is possible, try this
[answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250463/uiactivityview-attach-file-to-email/13419008#13419008

Comment: yes that works fine. Don't know why I didn't fry that before. Thanks. Please copy the comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes I think it is possible, try this

```
NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppDistributionGuide" ofType:@"pdf"]; 
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str]] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Comment: is there anyway to change the file name?

Comment: @MobileMon Hi, try to save file with needed name on the disk and set it instead "AppDistributionGuide". Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following way to achieve this. Preserve file name of attached files from read from URL:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    NSData *fileData;
    NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.pdf"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com/filename.pdf"]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Download Error:%@",error.description);
        }
        if (data) {
            fileData = data;
            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"File is saved to %@",filePath);
        }
    }];
    if(fileData && filePath) {
            UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]] applicationActivities:nil];
            [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
});
```